# Unity How do I set up a GUITexture as a button?

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I added GUITexture by going to Game object>>Create Other>>GUI Texture and added its texture in the inspector what I want now is when the user touches (Game is for android and IOS) that GUITexture to move cube up I tried this code

```
var up : GUITexture;
var player : Rigidbody2D;


function Update () {

    for (var evt : Touch in Input.touches) {

        var HitTest1 = up.HitTest(evt.position);

        if (evt.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {

            if(HitTest1){

                player.rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2(-2,0));

                fireButton.enabled = false;

            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

But it didn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (GUI.Button(Rect(10,10,50,50),up))
//Code to move cube up
```

This will create a GUIButton out of your texture. You would need to put this into the OnGUI function in your script. Here is a link to the reference for GUIButtons: [GUIButtons](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html)

Comment: yes but this wouldn't make my button off the screen on small screens devices  ??

Comment: The 10,10,50,50 just sets up the rect. So the tens just are the position of the button on the screen and the fifties are the size of the button. I don't know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have declared player as a rigidbody

```
var player : Rigidbody2D;
```

and below are trying to access its rigidbody

```
player.rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2(-2,0)); //this won't work
player.AddForce(Vector2(-2,0));//*use this instead*
```

**OR**

Try declaring player as gameobject

```
var player:GameObject
```

and add force correctly

```
player.rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2(-2,0));
```

Comment: 'AddForce' is not a member of 'UnityEngine.GameObject'.